# How to implement a character string in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

The main code itself works fine but I want to make use of character strings instead of the char, and it might be because I've overlooked something absurdly simple. Here is a small snippet of code:

```
struct Stack 
{ 
   char *SData; 
   int counter;
   struct Stack *next; 
}; 
  
struct Stack* StackNewNode(char SData) 
{ 
    struct Stack *stackNode = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); 
    stackNode->SData = SData;       //error here because of the difference of char, should i use []?
    stackNode->next = NULL; 
    return stackNode; 
}  

void PUSH(struct Stack **root, char SData) //this part only pushes a character
{ 
    struct Stack *stackNode = StackNewNode(SData); 
    stackNode->next = *root; 
    *root = stackNode; 
    
    printf("\n%c pushed to stack\n", SData); 
    
} 

void POP(struct Stack **root) 
{ 
    if (*root == NULL) 
    {
        return; 
    }
    struct Stack *temp = *root; 
    *root = (*root)->next; 
    char pop = temp->SData; //how should i pop a full string?
    free(temp); 
    printf("%c popped from stack\n", pop); 
}
```

I also want to implement a counter in the Stack. Should i use `Stack->counter++` or is there some other more correct way to do it?

Sorry for the wall of text its my first time here

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. You need to get that clear for yourself before anyone can help you. Is the Stack supposed to contain strings or chars ? You have some one way, some the other. If you want strings (char*) then you need to pass char* and handle the memory required,

Comment: You're not even *attempting* to store the `SData` anywhere...

Comment: `stackNode->SData = SData;` that should give you a warning. Something about "assign a pointer from an integer"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `counter` in `struct Stack` used anywhere in the code snippets you provided.  Assuming you want some count of the number of elements in the stack, it wouldn't make sense for this value to be part of the struct.  After all, you only need one count, not one attached to every element in the stack.  You would want to make this its own variable, perhaps a global defined in the same place as you define root.  Just make sure to initialize it to zero.

As for using character strings, you already have `char *SData`, which can point to a string.  All you need to do is change PUSH and StackNewNode to use `char*` parameter rather than `char` and then pass it a string, something like this:

```
PUSH(&root, "My string");
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with your current code have some type mismatch here: `stackNode->SData = SData;`

`stackNode->SData` is a char pointer and `SData` is a char. I assume your compiler warns you about that - never ignore warnings.

If you want to use C type string you need updates like:

1. Pass char pointer instead of char
2. Allocate memory for the string
3. Copy the passed string to the allocated memory
4. Free the memory when done

Something like:

```
struct Stack 
{ 
   char *SData; 
   int counter;
   struct Stack *next; 
}; 
  
struct Stack* StackNewNode(const char* str) 
{ 
    struct Stack *stackNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); 
    if (stackNode == NULL) exit(1);
    stackNode->SData = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (stackNode->SData == NULL) exit(1);
    strcpy(stackNode->SData, str);
    stackNode->next = NULL; 
    return stackNode; 
}  

void PUSH(struct Stack **root, const char* str)
{ 
    struct Stack *stackNode = StackNewNode(str); 
    stackNode->next = *root; 
    *root = stackNode; 
    
    printf("\n%s pushed to stack\n", str); 
    
} 

void POP(struct Stack **root) 
{ 
    if (*root == NULL) 
    {
        return; 
    }
    struct Stack *temp = *root; 
    *root = (*root)->next; 

    printf("%s popped from stack\n", temp->SData); 

    free(temp->SData);
    free(temp); 
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct Stack *root = NULL;
PUSH(&root, "Hello World");
```

**Adding a counter**

In your code you have placed `int counter;` inside every stack element. You can make that work but I would prefer two structs. One struct type holding information about the whole stack and another struct type for the elements.

Like:

```
struct StackNode
{ 
   char *SData; 
   struct StackNode *next; 
}; 

struct Stack
{ 
   int counter;
   struct StackNode *root; 
};
```

The functions would need some updates like:

```
void PUSH(struct Stack *stack, const char* str)
{ 
    struct StackNode *stackNode = StackNewNode(str); 
    stackNode->next = stack->root; 
    stack->root = stackNode; 
    ++stack->counter;          // Increment counter
    
    printf("\n%s pushed to stack\n", str); 
    
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct Stack stack = {0, NULL};
PUSH(&stack, "Hello World");
```